# Union all error must have equal number of expressions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

I am trying to run this query but I am getting this error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

What am I doing wrong here?  Please help.

```
SELECT      *
into       #xx 
From (
Select *
FROM #x 
union all  
select * from MartDB.DBO.BAW_AllSources_Stage1
) AAAsds
```

Comment: Error it self giving answer. To Union records check no. of columns in both the union tables. In your case it is #x and artDB.DBO.BAW_AllSources_Stage1. Also check there names.

Answer (score 6):

Your inner query part

```
Select *
FROM        #x 
union all  
select * 
from MartDB.DBO.BAW_AllSources_Stage1
```

has * in both queries participating in UNION.

Check and see if the both *s translate into same number of columns and data type in order.

Comment: @OP This is why your should avoid `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Both Selects must return the same number of columns and matching data types. If one Select returns an additional column, you can use `NULL` in the 2nd Select:

```
select integercol1, integercol2, varcharcol3, NULL
from t1
union
select integercol1, NULL,        varcharcol3, varcharcol4
from t2
```

. And if you got an error regarding non-matching data types, you can cast it like `cast(NULL as TIME)`

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft Docs:

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two
>   queries by using UNION:
>
> - The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all
>     queries.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

So you must guarantee that the select statements extract the same number of columns in the same order, so the best practice is to avoid `*` with `union` and `union all`.

Use explicit column names instead:

```
SELECT *
into       #xx 
From (
Select col_1, col_2, col_3 -- ... , col_n 
FROM        #x 
union all  
select col_1, col_2, col_3 -- ... , col_n 
from MartDB.DBO.BAW_AllSources_Stage1
) AAAsds
```